# Jquery datepicker subtract days

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using a jquery datepicker [link](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker/blob/master/README.md) in that i need to subtract 7 days from the current date. I've tried some code but its not working ie, days are not subtracting still showing current date itself. This is the code that i've tried yet. Any help is appreciable.

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khfueg4m/)

```
// datepicker
var $startDate = $('.start-date');
var $endDate = $('.end-date');

$startDate.datepicker({autoHide: true,format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});    
$startDate.datepicker("setDate", moment().subtract(7,'d').format('yyyy-mm-dd'));

$endDate.datepicker({
    autoHide: true,
    startDate: $startDate.datepicker('getDate'),
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
$endDate.datepicker('setDate', moment().format('yyyy-mm-dd'));
$startDate.on('change', function () {
    $endDate.datepicker('setStartDate', $startDate.datepicker('getDate'));
});
// datepicker
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example of this datepicker.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I've updated the question with demo fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [setDate](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/datepicker/blob/master/README.md#setdatedate) this datePicker documentation - You are **not** using `momentJS` format date function correctly. You need to `convert` a date from `YYYY-MM-DD` to a date object like for example: `Wed Sep 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)`

For that you can use [toDate()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) function of `momentJS` - Your `code` is working now as expected.

```
$startDate.datepicker("setDate", moment().subtract(7, 'd').toDate());
```

Or you can also use `native` Javascript [new Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) method like this below:

```
$startDate.datepicker("setDate", new Date(moment().subtract(7, 'd')));
```

You can also do this using just native `JavaScript` date function like this below **instead** of using moment library

```
var sub7Days = new Date();
sub7Days.setDate(sub7Days.getDate() - 7);
$startDate.datepicker("setDate", sub7Days);
```

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  // datepicker
  var $startDate = $('.start-date');
  var $endDate = $('.end-date');

  $startDate.datepicker({
    autoHide: true,
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });
  $startDate.datepicker("setDate", moment().subtract(7, 'd').toDate());

  $endDate.datepicker({
    autoHide: true,
    startDate: $startDate.datepicker('getDate'),
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
  });
  $endDate.datepicker('setDate', moment().toDate());

  $startDate.on('change', function() {
    $endDate.datepicker('setStartDate', $startDate.datepicker('getDate'));
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/css/datepicker.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/js/datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-Izh34nqeeR7/nwthfeE0SI3c8uhFSnqxV0sI9TvTcXiFJkMd6fB644O64BRq2P/LA/+7eRvCw4GmLsXksyTHBg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control start-date" id="datefrom" placeholder="Date From">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control end-date" id="dateto" placeholder="Date To">
</div>
```

Comment: @soorajspillai you are welcome - happy to help Sooraj. I have also added another method where you can simply use javascript as well instead of using moment library. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
          // datepicker
    var $startDate = $('.start-date');
    var $endDate = $('.end-date');

    $startDate.datepicker({autoHide: true,format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'});  
    console.log(moment().subtract(7,'days').format('yyyy-mm-D'));
    $startDate.datepicker("setDate", moment().subtract(7,'d').format('yyyy-mm-D'));
    
    $endDate.datepicker({
        autoHide: true,
        startDate: $startDate.datepicker('getDate'),
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
    $endDate.datepicker('setDate', moment().format('yyyy-mm-D'));
    $startDate.on('change', function () {
        $endDate.datepicker('setStartDate', $startDate.datepicker('getDate'));
    });
    // datepicker
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/css/datepicker.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/datepicker/js/datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-Izh34nqeeR7/nwthfeE0SI3c8uhFSnqxV0sI9TvTcXiFJkMd6fB644O64BRq2P/LA/+7eRvCw4GmLsXksyTHBg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control start-date" id="datefrom" placeholder="Date From">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control end-date" id="dateto" placeholder="Date To">
                        </div>
```

Changed `moment().subtract(7,'d').format('yyyy-mm-dd')` to `moment().subtract(7,'d').format('yyyy-mm-D')`